# C++ Inheriting Function Pointer that can be used with derived only methods

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

This is a simplified example of a design problem.

I have the class `Base`. It has a function pointer type and a protected variable of that function pointer type.

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base {

    typedef void (Base::*FunctionPointer) ( void );

protected:

    FunctionPointer pointer;

};

#endif  /* BASE_H */
```

Then I have the class `Derived` that inherits from `Base`. This class wants to be able to set the inherited `pointer` variable equal to addresses for it's own methods, not ones inherited or overridden from `Base`.

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base{

public:
    Derived()
    {
        pointer = &Derived::ProtectedMethod;
    }

    void ProtectedMethod()
    {

    }

};

#endif  /* DERIVED_H */
```

The problem is that the type of function pointers (`void (Base::*FunctionPointer) ( void )` and `void (Derived::*FunctionPointer) ( void )`) are different.

***In Short***

Is there a way to have a pointer variable in a base class that can be assigned to derived classes methods (not overridden)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your **Y** use case, instead of presenting the **X** problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @RSahu: it is not possible for they are unrelated types.
I'm adding this answer for the sake of curiosity.

You can do something similar with the CRTP idiom:

```
template<class D>
struct B {
    using FnType = void(D::*)();
    FnType ptr{nullptr};
};

struct D: B<D> {
    D(): B{} {
        ptr = &D::method;
    }

    void method() { }
};
```

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it is a viable solution at least.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to have a pointer variable in a base class that can be assigned to derived classes methods (not overridden)?

No, you cannot do that. They are unrelated types.

Comment: I know that it doesn't work because they are unrelated types. Is there a type that would work for all derived classes, i.e. one that is not class specific or one that works with classes related to each other through inheritance?